# counting unique factors in r

Tags: r, unique, r-factor

I would like to know the number of unique dams which gave birth on each of the birth dates recorded. My data frame is similar to this one:

```
dam <- c("2A11","2A11","2A12","2A12","2A12","4D23","4D23","1X23")
bdate <- c("2009-10-01","2009-10-01","2009-10-01","2009-10-01",
           "2009-10-01","2009-10-03","2009-10-03","2009-10-03")
mydf <- data.frame(dam,bdate)
mydf
#    dam      bdate
# 1 2A11 2009-10-01
# 2 2A11 2009-10-01
# 3 2A12 2009-10-01
# 4 2A12 2009-10-01
# 5 2A12 2009-10-01
# 6 4D23 2009-10-03
# 7 4D23 2009-10-03
# 8 1X23 2009-10-03
```

I used `aggregate(dam ~ bdate, data=mydf, FUN=length)` but it counts all the dams that gave birth on a particular date

```
bdate dam
1 2009-10-01   5
2 2009-10-03   3
```

Instead, I need to have something like this:

```
mydf2
  bdate      dam
1 2009-10-01  2
2 2009-10-03  2
```

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about:

```
aggregate(dam ~ bdate, data=mydf, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also run `unique` on the data first:

```
aggregate(dam ~ bdate, data=unique(mydf[c("dam","date")]), FUN=length)
```

Then you could also use `table` instead of `aggregate`, though the output is a little different.

```
> table(unique(mydf[c("dam","date")])$bdate)

2009-10-01 2009-10-03 
         2          2
```

Comment: +1 Nice idea to run `unique` first.  Do note, however, that this will only work if `mydf` only contains `dam` and `bdate`.

Comment: @Joshua: that's exactly correct. I tried to run on my data and it could not get what I wanted. The line you provided did exactly what I was looking for as my data contains about 60 other variables.

Comment: If you do have other variables, then just use the two columns you want.  See edit.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an example of how to think of the problem and one of the approaches on how to solve it.

```
split.mydf <- with(mydf, split(x = mydf, f = bdate)) #each list element has only one date.
# it's just a matter of counting unique dams
unique.mydf <- lapply(X = split.mydf, FUN = unique)
#and then count the number of unique elements
unilen.mydf <- lapply(unique.mydf, length)
#you can do these two last steps in one go like so
lapply(split.mydf, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))

as.data.frame(unlist(unilen.mydf)) #data.frame is just a special list, so this is water to your mill

           unlist(unilen.mydf)
2009-10-01                   2
2009-10-03                   2
```

Comment: Nice example: especially useful for those with a slightly different problem who find this thread as it separates out the steps for easier understanding.

Answer (score 3):

In **dplyr** you can use `n_distinct` :

```
library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
  group_by(bdate) %>%
  summarize(dam = n_distinct(dam))
```